# Image source path in application_helper.rb in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image-processing, asset-pipeline

In my Rails app, I am using a img tag in Application_helper.rb, But I think Assests pipeline is not working here, So the image is not loading on the page. And Browser console show as error of "failed to load the given URL".
One line fro my code block is as :

```
text = "<input type='checkbox'/><img src='Icon_Bar.png' />#{r[:value]}<span class='small'>(#{r[:count]})</span>".html_safe
```

And it works fine, when I used any online path for the image. Please Help.

Comment: show your ruby on rails code for the image

Comment: I am using it as it is. Actually its in a function in application_helper and it will return the text on the page. You can see I have used checkbox too. All these works fine, but image source is not working in relative mode, When I use a absolute link of a online image then it works.

Comment: I updated the answer, check it.

Comment: <img src='#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/Icon_Bar.png'/> gives me full path but still its not loading the image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this,

```
text = "<input type='checkbox'/><img src='/assets/Icon_Bar.png' />#{r[:value]}<span class='small'>(#{r[:count]})</span>".html_safe
```

Add `/assets/` before the image.extension.

when `Icon_Bar.png` in `assets/images/Icon_Bar.png`

Comment: Sorry, It shows so many syntax errors. And You know Its displaying all, except loading the image from assests/images.

Comment: no,it not works. It prints image tag as it is. <%= image_tag 'Icon_Bar.png' %>

Comment: did you used the + symbol?

Comment: @rathore Just give a last try with my updated answer and let me know.

Comment: In html you need to add the full path like what we do normally. Cool.. and give a upvote if you satisfied my answer.. :)

Comment: I have checked it as Correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

`<img src="<%= image_path('Icon_Bar.png') %>" />`

The doc is here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-image_path

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
<%= image_tag("Icon_Bar.png") %>
```

Watch out for the capital letters , they also matter in referencing to assets.

Comment: What is the exact place of your `Icon_Bar.png`? It should be in one of the asset directories.

Comment: /media/rathore/6EC44211C441DC49/railapps/28_01_2013_without_image_new/app/assets/images/Icon_Bar.png

Comment: Whole this? I think it is not an asset directory. Try to place it in one of default asset dirs :`app/assets/images` , `lib/assets/images` or `vendors/assets/images` . The Sprockets gem gets confused in your case...

Comment: yeah its assests directory. I provided in a comment how I am getting Rails.root.

Comment: check my path once again , I am Using **app/assets/images**